# zshrc alias gets executed when launching a new terminal

Tags: zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I am using `zsh` and in my config I am adding another alias :

```
alias recursively_git_pull_all_repo="for dir in $(find . -name ".git"); do cd ${dir%/*}; git pull ; cd -; done"
```

However this alias seems to get executed every time I open a new terminal (or at least it slows down starting up a new terminal considerably).

How can I add this alias without it being launched every time I open a new terminal ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR** <sub>(or should it be TL;WR - "too long, won't read"?)</sub>

```
alias recursively_git_pull_all_repo='for dir in **/.git(/:h); git -C $dir pull'
```

---

You are at least partially correct in that a part of this command is run when the alias is declared. This has two effects:

1. Loading the alias takes time
2. The alias **does not work**

### Explanation

You are declaring the alias in double quotes, which allows for parameter expansion. That means that the parts `$(find . -name ".git")` and `${dir%/*}` will be expanded and substituted at the time the alias is declared taking the values they produce at the time.

For `$(find . -name ".git")` this means that `.` is most likely `$HOME` and the construct is replaced by a newline separated list of all `.git` directories (and other file-like objects) in your home directory.

`${dir%/*}` will probably be substituted with an empty string as `dir` is most likely not set. Remember: the alias itself is not executed at that time, so `dir` will not be set by the `for` loop.

This means that:

```
alias recursively_git_pull_all_repo="for dir in $(find . -name ".git"); do cd ${dir%/*}; git pull ; cd -; done"
```

will effectively be saved as something like

```
alias recursively_git_pull_all_repo="for dir in docs/repo1/.git
docs/repo2/.git
otherdocs/repo/.git
whatever/.git; do
cd ; git pull ; cd -; done"
```

This will - fortunately - fail with an `zsh: command not found: docs/repo2/.git` error because of the newline after the first repository. If it did not, it would change into your home directory repeatedly (`cd` without parameter) and try to do `git pull`.

### Solution

The quick solution would be to just use single quotes, when declaring the alias, that way the command and parameter will substituted when the alias is run, not when it is declared.

**But** there are still some other problems with that:

- if any of the directory names contain white spaces, this will fail because for will interpret it as two values
- if you cannot switch into one of the found directories, `git pull` will be run from the current directory instead. This can actually happen if the *execute* flag is not set on a directory in the path.
- without additional parameters `find` will also list non-directories named `.git`

**Instead** I would suggest to use what `zsh` has to offer:

```
alias recursively_git_pull_all_repo='for dir in **/.git(/:h); git -C $dir pull'
```

- you do not actually need `find` to get a list of the directories. The `**` glob will be recursively expanded to all directories. So `**/.git` will be expanded to all paths with `.git` as last element.
- you can use glob qualifiers to restrict expansions to elements that fulfill certain criteria. In this case `**/.git(/)` the qualifier `/` means: "only directories".
- you can also history expansion modifiers as glob qualifiers. This is done with a `:` followed by the modifier - in this case `h`, which removes the last path component (like the program `dirname`, or `${dir%/*}` from your example).
- you do not actually need do change directory into a git repository in order to do use `git`; you can tell `git` where to work with `git -C <path>`
- as you are now only running one command inside the loop, you can use the short syntax for `for`, meaning no `do ...; done`.

---

Fun fact: If you use `d` instead of `dir`, another short form of `for` and the option `GLOB_STAR_SHORT` is enabled (requires zsh >= 5.2), you can use:

```
for d (**.git(/:h))git -C $d pull
```

which is only 4 characters longer than your alias name. Yes, I know about completion. But there is also history searching .

Comment: Really nice explanation. I will have to revisit some of my existing alias that work but it may have been pure luck. In a `.bashrc`, would you have used the function approach that @Hashier suggested ?

Comment: Maybe? Even in the case of `zsh` it is a bit of a toss-up: alias or function, it works either way. I mainly used alias because it was in the question and there was no real need for a function. `bash` does not have glob qualifiers, thus requiring the use of `find`, and needs some extra care with quoting (for example, you would have to use double quotes around `$dir` to be safe from white spaces). So I probably may have gone with a function there, mainly to keep it readable.

Comment: Really nice answer. Thank you for the explanation. In my case, I just needed to replace all the `"` with `'` in the aliases (not in the actual command, of course). ZSH boot time went from 20s to ~2s! (Yes, I have a lot of aliases)

Answer (score 3):

You could put it in a function instead of an alias:

```
$ cat zshFunction

function recursively_git_pull_all_repo () {
    echo "Executing code"
    for dir in $(find . -name ".git"); do cd ${dir%/*}; git pull ; cd -; done
}

$ recursively_git_pull_all_repo
zsh: command not found: recursively_git_pull_all_repo

$ source zshFunction                                                                                                                                                      
$

$ recursively_git_pull_all_repo
Executing code
$
```

Comment: Still not advised to loop over directories like that.  But +1 for the function over alias.